# The spectral density of fractional Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X_t$ be the fractional Ornstein-Uhlenbeck, thus
\begin{equation}\label{eq:mfou}
dX_{t}=-\theta X_{t}dt+ dB_{t}^{H}\,,
\end{equation}
where $B_{t}^{H}$ is a fractional Brownian motion with the Hurst parameter $H$ and $\theta>0$.

From Page 142, Eq (6.1) of Hult's thesis (Chapter 6
Parameter estimation for discretely observed fractional
Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process in[enter link description here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Henrik-Hult-2/publication/267950872_Topics_on_fractional_Brownian_motion_and_regular_variation_for_stochastic_processes/links/551e927b0cf2a2d9e13c0128/Topics-on-fractional-Brownian-motion-and-regular-variation-for-stochastic-processes.pdf) ), we can see that the spectral density of fractional Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process is
\begin{equation}
f(\xi)=\sigma^{2} C(H)(2 \pi)^{-1}|\xi|^{1-2 H}\left(\theta^{2}+\xi^{2}\right)^{-1} .
\end{equation}

However, from Page 145, we can see that the spectral density for the fractional Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process is given by
$$
f_{\Delta}(\lambda)=\frac{\sigma^{2} C(H) \Delta^{2 H}}{2 \pi} \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{|\lambda+2 \pi k|^{1-2 H}}{(\Delta \theta)^{2}+(\lambda+2 \pi k)^{2}}
$$

Which one is correct or both are right?

Any help is warmly welcomed.